# Does $p\mid f(m)+f(n)\leftrightarrow p\mid f(m+n)$ imply $f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a function such that:
$$(\forall p: \mathrm{~prime~})(\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N})(p\mid f(m)+f(n)\leftrightarrow p\mid f(m+n))$$

is $f$ linear?

---

by linear I mean:

$$(\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N})(f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n))$$

Comment: $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit?

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams: by $\iff$ I'm mean metalanguage equivalence. and $p:prime$ is more clear. but I edited | to \mid . thanks.

Comment: No problem, I was just wondering (although you could change the $p : prime$ to $p : \mathrm{prime}$ (\mathrm{prime}) so it doesn't get italicized.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it all comes down to the presence of duplicate primes in the factorization of the left not present in the right, or vice-versa. If we can prove there are no duplicates not present in the other side, then $f$ is linear (because both sides would have the exact same prime factors and therefore must be equal). If we could come up with an $f$ that introduces a duplicate prime without introducing a new prime, that would be a counter-example. I can't seem to do either right now.

Answer (score 3):

There are many counterexamples which are not constant.

Take any partition of $\mathbb{N}$ into 2 nonempty sets $A, B$, and take

\begin{equation}
f(n)= \begin{cases} 6& \text{if} \, n \in A \\ 18& \text{if} \, n \in B \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Let me know if you want more elaborate counterexamples.

Comment: you're right. your example can be generalized. If it can be generalized to an infinite valued function, it would be great. However it has been proved there's no surjective counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

I found one trivial nonlinear $f$. Let $f\equiv2$. then for arbitrary $m$ and $n$ we have:
$$p\mid f(m+n)\leftrightarrow p\mid 2 \leftrightarrow p=2 \leftrightarrow p\mid 4 \leftrightarrow p\mid f(m)+f(n)$$

but
$$f(1+1)=2\ne4=f(1)+f(1)$$

Other exmples are constant functions $f\equiv2n_0$ where $n_0$is any positive integer. It seems these are all possible constant functions.

But I guess nonconstant functions are linear.

At least if $f$ is onto then $(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(f(n)=n)$! But non-surjective functions are interesting for me. Is there any non constant non surjective example?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. For example, consider $f(n) = 2^n$.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the stated property. $f(1) + f(2) = 2 + 4 = 6$, so $3$ divides it. But $3$ does not divide $f(1 + 2) = 8$.